# Documentation: merge [html5-canvas] documentation into [html]

Tags: support, documentation, tag-alias-request

As the title says. [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) has 18 documentation topics that should be under [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html). Can a Stack Exchange staff member facilitate this merge?

Comment: Fair point @Aurora0001. However, I suppose then another question would be, why *should* these topics be merged underneath HTML?

Comment: If it has 18 topics, it should probably be its own tag. HTML itself already has 38 topics. I would think that increasing that to 56 would make it even harder to find anything.

Comment: No, this should not happen. Moreover, you need to revisit your role in Documentation as you are using a very heavy hand in leveraging robo review approval to modify content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a bad idea. Only the `<canvas>` element itself is actually relevant to the base HTML documentation. Most of the canvas documentation seen there is actually JavaScript APIs that were simply defined in the specification *along with* HTML and have nothing to do with the HTML language itself. If anything, it'd make far more sense to merge that documentation with the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) docs if it really needed to be merged anywhere. Dumping it into HTML simply because it's a loosely related cousin is not the way to go.